# project structure for wrapping many c++ classes in cython to a single shared object

Tags: c++, python, design-patterns, cython

I have found partial answers between the docs, mailing lists, and [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300660/cython-and-distutils), but I wanted to get a more direct answer addressing my specifics...

I'm learning cython by trying to wrap small parts, little by little, of a library that I am already using that is currently wrapped in boost::python. I have contributed a tiny bit to this boost wrapper, and am using it as a c++ reference, while at the same time I am using [ZeroMQ Python bindings](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/tree/master/zmq/core) as a cython reference.

My question is about project structure. The current boost version of this lib compiles to a single `.so`, and that is my goal. I quickly found out that you cannot directly compile multiple `.pyx` modules to a single `.so`. I then started going down the route of defining the `cppclass`'s in `pxd` files, and their corresponding python exported implementation classes in `.pxi`, and was trying to include them into a single `pyx` for compilation. While it worked at first, once I wrote a little more I hit problems with conflicting multiple definitions because of the `pxi` includes in different places.

I would love to hear a proper organizational approach that addresses the following questions and goals:

- Naming the public classes the same as the `cppclass` (I am doing this now by having the cppclass in a different named `pyd` and using the imported namespace to handle the similar names, ala [Using cimport to resolve naming conflicts](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#using-cimport-to-resolve-naming-conflicts))
- Single `.so` as the compiled output ([acceptable approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300660/cython-and-distutils))
- Do I use the `pyx` multi-include approach into the main `pyx` for that alone, or should that main `pyx` contain anything else beyond just holding the includes?
- Where to centrally define constants that will be exported in python?
- Is there a preferred folder structure? Right now I have everything in a big `src` directory beneath my `setup.py`. It gets confusing seeing so many `pxi, pxd, pyx` files.
- Are `pxi` completely unnecessary now? If not, do I need to use a cython-style ifndef guard to handle the multiple inclusions between different modules?
- I know the ZeroMQ python bindings build multiple modules and use the package approach by including them through `__init__.py`. Is that really the proper approach with cython?

For reference, the project I am practicing to re-wrap is [PyOpenNI](https://github.com/justinfx/PyOpenNI) (openni). The pattern this boost project takes is to collect the common objects in one place, and then define a 1-to-1 header definition with the source, and then there is a huge wrapper that collects all of the definitions into the single location. And also the added custom exception handling and utilities.

Comment: This is a possible approach for the part of the question about linking different cython-extension into one single shared object: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52714500/5769463

Comment: @ead Thanks for that link. Pretty interesting! I might have tried that with a project started years ago that ended up having 10 modules that just get imported into the main namespace.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

While waiting for a definitive answer, I kept playing around with organizing my code. The including of `pyx` files into a single `pyx` for compilation has been working so far.

My `setup.py` is simple like:

```
ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        "openni", 
        ["src/openni.pyx"], 
        language="c++",
        include_dirs=['src/', '/usr/include/ni'],
        libraries=['OpenNI'],
    )
],
```

The main `openni.pyx` looks like:

```
include "constants.pyx"
include "exceptions.pyx"
include "context.pyx"
...
```

I have a common `libopenni.pxd` to provide declaration-only externs to the rest of the modules.

I name my `cppclass` declarations a different `pxd` name than the `pyx` class definitions to avoid name collision:

*xncontext.pxd*

```
cdef extern from "XnCppWrapper.h" namespace "xn":
    cdef cppclass Context:
           ...
```

*context.pyx:*

```
from libopenni cimport *
from xncontext cimport Context as c_Context 

cdef class Context:
    cdef c_Context *handle   
        ...
```

Comment: Can you point to the rest of the code that you have put together for this wrapper?  I'm running into a similar problem with a similar resolution.  It's not nice but it works.

Comment: Hey. So this wasn't anything that ended up in a public repo. Most of my latest examples of this structure aren't online but here is one that I did shortly after this:https://github.com/chadmv/plow/tree/master/lib/python/src

Comment: What I do now is keep the pxi files in and include subdirectory to make it clean. And I just have the main single pyx above it along with the pxd that contains all the extern declarations for binding to the C/CPP

Answer (score 0):

Answering *Is there a preferred folder structure?*

Yes, the preferred folder structure for Cython's `.pyx` and `.pxd` files is to treat them exactly as you would your `.py` files: one per module, in a well-organized package structure. `__init__.pxd` files can be provided just like `__init__.py` files to assemble a curated set of symbols to collect a curated set of symbols from its submodules/packages for cimporting.

True, this produces one `.so` file per module, but these files are hidden away in the build directory. The same is true of Python's builting modules; there's a corresponding `.so` files for each one of those. Is this a problem?

Comment: As of recently I had converted to a multi so approach and importing them into a single namespace via the __init__.py

Comment: I wasn't aware that an __init__.pxd had significance st the module level

Comment: Separate .so files for every module might be a problem if you apply a licensing (protection) to those .so files when licensing takes some time to initialize.