# Python can't import extensions generated in a nested hierarchy

Tags: python, cython, setuptools

I have a library with a deeply nested module hierarchy, with a structure such as

```
src/
  my_library/
    __init__.py
    my_module/
      __init__.py
      my_submodule.py
```

Such that for example one might be able to write `from my_library.my_module.my_submodule import Foo` etc.

I have a function which walks the file tree, discovering all of python modules and converting them into `Extension` objects which are passed into `cythonize`, effectively cythonizing the whole module. Inspecting the before they are built, they look (in dictionary form) something like:

```
(Pdb) pp vars(e)
{'define_macros': [],
 'depends': [],
 'export_symbols': [],
 'extra_compile_args': [],
 'extra_link_args': [],
 'extra_objects': [],
 'include_dirs': [],
 'language': None,
 'libraries': [],
 'library_dirs': [],
 'name': 'my_library.my_module.my_submodule',
 'optional': None,
 'runtime_library_dirs': [],
 'sources': ['src/my_library/my_module/my_submodule.c'],
 'swig_opts': [],
 'undef_macros': []}
```

The list of extensions is then passed into the `ext_modules` argument of `setuptools.setup()`. Invoking `setup.py install` results in a bunch of compilations as expected, which is great. However, files are written to a directory structure mirroring their location prior to being compiled, so for example it ends up with something like

```
lib/python3.4/site-packages/
  my_library.cpython-34m.so
  my_library/
    my_module.cpython-34m.so
    my_module/
      my_submodule.cpython-34m.so
```

Because of this nested structure, I am only able to import the top-level object when the installed-to directory is in my `PYTHONPATH`:

```
>>> import my_library
>>> my_library.foo()
'foo'
>>> import my_library.my_module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'my_library.my_module'
```

It seems that since the generated files are written to subdirectories rather than directly to the `site-packages` folder, the python interpreter is unable to discover them. I don't know much about python extensions, but looking around I didn't see a way to get python to put them in a flat structure rather than nested, nor do I know if there's a way to get python to discover `.so` files written to subdirectories -- perhaps by adding `__init__.py` files?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you "double define" `my_library`: once via the `__init__.py` file and once via the cython code.

The solution is to have a "pure Python" module hierarchy and to create cython modules as elements in that hierarchy, outside any conflicts with the Python modules.

```
src/   
    my_library/
        __init__.py
        my_first_cython_module.pyx
        my_module/
            __init__.py
            my_submodule.py
            other_cython_module.pyx
```

This way, you can do `import my_library.my_module`, etc. For the Cython modules, import `my_library.my_first_cython_module`, etc.

You can keep your current import names by importing the Cython code from the `__init__.py` files:

```
from my_library.my_first_cython_module import foo
```

Comment: The thing is that I'm trying to take a pure python library and compile *all* of the code in it with cython. Basically, the goal is to have a library with the same structure as the python one, but built entirely with shared object files.

Comment: It is impossible, see this other SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157363/collapse-multiple-submodules-to-one-cython-extension and the Cython FAQ: https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/FAQ#how-to-compile-cython-with-subpackages