# cython cmake module runtime error

Tags: c++, cmake, cython

To get close to a MWE, I have an example [project](https://github.com/phil0stine/test_cython_cmake) that illustrates my problem.
The project tries to perform a simple operation on a wrapped C++ class, in this case a [PCLHeader](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/structpcl_1_1_p_c_l_header.html) object.

I am pretty sure the problem lies in the fact that my `cmake` call includes two `.pyx` files. 
`cython_add_module(test_cython common.pyx test_cython.pyx)`.

Based on the documentation in `UseCython.cmake`, which is part of the project, this call should be okay as far as I can tell.

When I build this project, then try to import the resulting library, Python fails to import *the first time only*.

```
In [1]: import test_cython
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-158d7481838a> in <module>()
----> 1 import test_cython

common.pxd in init test_cython (/Users/phil/devel/test_cython/build/test_cython.cxx:1424)()

ImportError: No module named common

In [2]: import test_cython

In [3]:
```

As an aside, if anybody could steer me toward a better design if this is wrong in some way, I would appreciate it. For example, I cannot understand why [this line](https://github.com/phil0stine/test_cython_cmake/blob/5f8699e366526b3e0a76790e9c90b1b23570609a/test_cython.pyx#L31) causes compile errors based on my setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cython_add_module(test_cython common.pyx test_cython.pyx)
```

This compiles `common` and `test_cython` into a single module (`test_cython.so` or something similar). When you import that however it will run the initialization for `test_cython` but not for `common`. (When Python loads a compiled module it runs a function called `PyInit_<modulename>` or `init_<modulename>` depending on on if you're running Python 2 or 3. Although `PyInit_common` exists, it isn't called since you're importing `test_cython`)

At some point within `test_cython` you then attempt to import from `common`. The Python import mechanism is based around each module being a separate file - it first searches through a list of different file types(`common.py`, `common.pyc`, `common.so` etc.) and finds none of them. Therefore an `ImportError` is raised.

[Cython doesn't support compiling multiple modules into a single .so file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157363/collapse-multiple-submodules-to-one-cython-extension). (You can occasionally get away with things that look similar though, provided they only use C interfaces - it still isn't a great idea even if it seems to work). What you need to do is compile `test_cython.pyx` to one module and `common.pyx` to a second module:

```
cython_add_module(test_cython test_cython.pyx)
cython_add_module(common common.pyx)
```

Comment: With respect to your compile time error - it's probably failing to deduce types correctly and you can probably fix that by specifying them. However I don't know what the error actually is.

Comment: I tried your solution during debug but I think I followed it up with a call to `target_link_libraries` which failed. It didn't occur to me that it would just work without linking, but it makes sense in the context of importing. Thanks, I will test shortly

Comment: Worked, as expected. I think you need to edit for me to upvote (I think my child errantly downvoted), but I will accept in either case. As for the compile error, I am getting the classic `Cannot convert Python object to 'PCLHeader'`, even for the following line `cdef PCLHeader hw = HeaderWrap(h).header_cpp[0]`. In any case thank you.

Comment: I think you need to `cimport HeaderWrap` from `common` so that Cython is aware that it is a `cdef` type and thus can use its `cdef` attributes. I'm not in a position to test that right now though