# Compile multi-python file using Cython and generate a so

Tags: python, cython

I have some python files, and all operation exposure to others in a Main file. I want to compile them and distribute one `.so` for others.

I try cython to compile them but more than one `.so` generated (works but not perfect).

example:

The folder structure is:

```
CythonExample/
|——for_call.py
|——setup.py
|——Student.py
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(["Student.py", "for_call.py"]),
)
```

`python setup.py build_ext --inplace` then I get `Student.so` and `for_call.so`.

I modify setup.py to:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name='sayname',
    ext_modules=cythonize(Extension("sayname", sources=["Student.py", "for_call.py"], language="c")),
)
```

then 
`python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, well, only `sayname.so` generated. but when i try to import it.

```
import sayname

ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initsayname)
```

thanks.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157363/collapse-multiple-submodules-to-one-cython-extension?noredirect=1&lq=1) might also be useful, but describes a slightly different folder structure. But the general upshot is this isn't _really_ supported in Cython but it's sometimes possible to do it in a hacky way