# Is the import order of extensions in module filenames guaranteed in Python?

Tags: python, python-import, python-extensions

Experimentally, I verified that when a compiled `extension.pyd` (or `.so`) and plain `extension.py` both exist in the same directory, the `.pyd` file gets imported first ; the `.py` is only imported if the `.pyd` file is not found:

```py
In [1]: import extension

In [2]: extension.__file__
Out[2]: 'extension.pyd'

In [3]: import glob; glob.glob("extension.py*")
Out[3]: ['extension.py', 'extension.pyd']
```

Is that guaranteed to be the same for all versions of Python, and can I rely on this to add logic to the `.py` file that is only executed when the `.pyd` file is not found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, I was not able to find a reference stating, that extensions must be loaded before py-files, thus it is probably safer to treat it as an implementation detail (unless somebody provides a reference). Even if this details is stable for all versions at least back to 2.7.

When a module is imported, it first looked-up in the cache (i.e. [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules)) and if not yet there, the finders from [`sys.meta_path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.meta_path) are used. Usually, `sys.meta_path` consist of `BuiltinImporter`, `FrozenImporter` and [`PathFinder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.PathFinder), where `PathFinder` is responsible for finding the modules on disk/python-path.

`PathFinder` provides some caching functionality to speed-up the look-up, but it basically [delegates the search](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L1264) to [hooks](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L1233-L1244) from [`sys.path_hooks`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path_hooks) - an overview can be found for example in [PEP 302](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/).

Usually, `sys.path_hooks` consist of `zipimporter`, which make the import of zipped files possible, [and](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L1605) a wrapped  [`FileFinder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.FileFinder), which is the working horse of the whole import-machinery.

`FileFinder` tries out different suffices (i.e. `.so`, `.py`, `.pyc`) in a given order, which is established by [`_get_supported_file_loaders()`-method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L1525-L1533):

```
def _get_supported_file_loaders():
    """Returns a list of file-based module loaders.
    Each item is a tuple (loader, suffixes).
    """
    extensions = ExtensionFileLoader, _imp.extension_suffixes()
    source = SourceFileLoader, SOURCE_SUFFIXES
    bytecode = SourcelessFileLoader, BYTECODE_SUFFIXES
    return [extensions, source, bytecode]
```

As one can see:

- extensions come before source-files (i.e py-files)
- source-files come before pyc-files

Obviously, `sys.meta_path` as well as `sys.path_hooks` can be manipulated in a way, which establish an arbitrary order of load-preferences.

As personal note: I would try to avoid the situation where py- and so/pyd-files are next to eachother.

Comment: Thanks, that's a well-researched answer! I basically defaulted to the same idea (avoiding this situation) in the absence of a well-defined behavior in the standard.