# How to load a dylib-file as CPython-extension?

Tags: python, macos, cpython

This has been asked before (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2582504/5769463)), but the given solution (i.e. renaming file to `*.so`) is not acceptable. I have a CPython extension called `name.dylib`, which cannot be imported. If the filename is changed to use `name.so` it is imported correctly. Changing the filename is not an option**, and should not be necessary.

Python has a lot of hooks for searching for modules, so there must be a way to make it recognise a dylib-file. Can someone show how to do this? Using a low level import which spells out the whole filename is not nice but is an acceptable solution.

** because the build code forces dylib, and, other contexts I have assume it. The extension module is dual purpose, it can by used both as an ordinary shared library and a Python extension. Using a symlink does work, but is a last resort because it requires manual intervention in an automated process.

Answer (score 0):

You could manipulate [`sys.path_hooks`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path_hooks) and replace [`FileFinder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.FileFinder)-hook with one which would accept `.dylib`-extensions. But see also the simpler but less convinient alternative which would import given the full file-name of the extension.

More information how `.so`, `.py` and `.pyc` files are imported can be found for example in this [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56119980/5769463).

This manipulation could look like following:

```py
import sys
import importlib
from importlib.machinery import FileFinder, ExtensionFileLoader

# pick right loader for .dylib-files:
dylib_extension = ExtensionFileLoader, ['.dylib']

# add dylib-support to file-extension supported per default
all_supported_loaders = [dylib_extension]+ importlib._bootstrap_external._get_supported_file_loaders()


# replace the last hook (i.e. FileFinder) with one recognizing `.dylib` as well:
sys.path_hooks.pop()
sys.path_hooks.append(FileFinder.path_hook(*all_supported_loaders))

#and now import name.dylib via
import name
```

This **must** be the first code executed, when python-script starts to run. Other modules might not expect `sys.path_hooks` being manipulated somewhere during the run of the program, so there might be some problems with other modules (like `pdb`, `traceback` and so). For example:

```py
import pdb

#above code

import name
```

will fail, while

```py
#above code

import pdb

import name
```

will work, as `pdb` seems to manipulate the import-machinery.

---

Normally, `FileFinder`-hook is the last in the `sys.path_hooks`, because it is the last resort, once [`path_hook_for_FileFinder`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L1488-L1492) is called for a path, the finder is returned (`ImportError` should be raised if `PathFinder` should look at further hooks):

```
def path_hook_for_FileFinder(path):
        """Path hook for importlib.machinery.FileFinder."""
        if not _path_isdir(path):
            raise ImportError('only directories are supported', path=path)
        return cls(path, *loader_details) # HERE Finder is returned!
```

However, one might want to be sure and check, that **really** the right hook is replaced.

---

A simpler alternative would be to use `imp.load_dynamic` (neglecting for the moment that `imp` is depricated):

```
import imp
imp.load_dynamic('name', 'name.dylib') # or what ever path is used
```

That might be more robust than the first solution (no problems with `pdb` for example) but less convinient for bigger projects.