# How can I import pyx/pxd in Cython like cpp/h in c++?

Tags: python, cython

I have:

**my_volume.pxd**

```
cdef float c_cube(float x)
```

**my_volume.pyx**

```
cdef float c_cube(float x):
    return x * x * x
```

**my_test.pyx**

```
from my_volume cimport c_cube

def cube(x):
    return c_cube(x)
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import os

ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/'

setup(
name = 'c_optimized',
ext_modules=[
    Extension('my_test',
        sources=[ROOT_DIR + 'test/my_test.pyx',
                 ROOT_DIR + 'test/my_volume.pyx',
                ],
        extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11", "-O3"],
        include_dirs=[ROOT_DIR],
        extra_link_args=["-std=c++11", "-O3"],
        language='c++'),

],
cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
script_args = ['build_ext'],
options = {'build_ext': {'inplace': True, 'force': True}},

)
```

**test_c.py**

```
...
print(cpp.cube(3))
```

Build errors:

1) multiple definition of `PyInit_my_test'
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/home/user/projects/python/service_core/c_optimized/test/my_test.o:/home/user/projects/python/service_core/c_optimized/test/my_test.cpp:783: first defined here
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/home/user/projects/python/service_core/c_optimized/test/my_volume.o: In function`PyInit_my_test':

2) multiple definition of `__pyx_module_is_main_my_test'
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/home/user/projects/python/service_core/c_optimized/test/my_test.o:/home/user/projects/python/service_core/c_optimized/test/my_test.cpp:1280: first defined here

***What's wrong with my code? I need pxd/pyx common files that I can include to other. How can I include code from one pyx file to another?***

Comment: What you are trying to do is to put multiple pyx-files into one extension (https://stackoverflow.com/q/30157363/5769463). It is not what you want/should do: Create an extension per pyx-file.

Comment: What about https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html (Sharing C Functions)? They do what i need.

Comment: They use `setup(ext_modules=cythonize(["landscaping.pyx", "shrubbing.pyx"]))`, which creates two different extensions - this is quite a difference to you setup.py.

Comment: So, no way to build 2 pyx in one extension and use pxd as header?

Comment: The question is not whether you could (you can, see the link above), but whether you should. I think rather not.

Answer (score 0):

I found part solution.
**setup.py**

```
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import os

ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/'

test = Extension('test',    
            sources=[ROOT_DIR + 'test/my_test.pyx'],
            extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11", "-O3"],
            extra_link_args=["-std=c++11", "-O3"],
            include_dirs=[ROOT_DIR, '.'],
            language='c++')

volume = Extension('volume',
            sources=[ROOT_DIR + 'test/my_volume.pyx'],
            extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11", "-O3"],
            extra_link_args=["-std=c++11", "-O3"],
            include_dirs=[ROOT_DIR, '.'],
            language='c++')

setup(
     ext_modules=cythonize([test, volume])
)
```

This solution gives control over compilation:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/user/projects/python/service_core/c_optimized/ -I. -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c /home/user/projects/python/service_core/c_optimized/test/my_test.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/home/user/projects/python/service_core/c_optimized/test/my_test.o -std=c++11 -O3
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/home/user/projects/python/service_core/c_optimized/test/my_test.o -o /home/user/projects/python/service_core/test.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -std=c++11 -O3
building 'volume' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/user/projects/python/service_core/c_optimized/ -I. -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c /home/user/projects/python/service_core/c_optimized/test/my_volume.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/home/user/projects/python/service_core/c_optimized/test/my_volume.o -std=c++11 -O3
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/home/user/projects/python/service_core/c_optimized/test/my_volume.o -o /home/user/projects/python/service_core/volume.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -std=c++11 -O3
```