# Can a native extension support multiple modules?

Tags: python, python-module, cpython, python-c-api

So in python native extension, is it possible to implement multiple modules in a single shared library? Then what would be the name of the shared library should be?

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_foo(void) { PyModule_Create(...); }
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_bar(void) { PyModule_Create(...); }
```

Should I name the library file `foo.so` or `bar.so`? and will `import foo;` import just `foo` or both `foo` and `bar` modules?

Comment: [Here's a relevant question that does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157363/collapse-multiple-submodules-to-one-cython-extension) what you want (but using Cython). You should be able to use substantially the same approach here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. The easiest way is to create hardlinks named after each module for `importlib` to be able to *find* the module. The statement `import <x>` imports the module named `<x>` by looking for an exported `PyInit_<x>` function from `<x>-*.so`.

So say, you build as `foo.so` and create `bar.so` as a hardlink to `foo.so`. Your package structure would look like:

```
/mypackage/__init__.py
/mypackage/foo.so
/mypackage/bar.so -> foo.so # hardlink
```

Comment: Does  setuptools support auto creation of the hardlink?

Comment: With setuptools, you can add two extensions with different names, e.g.,: 

`setup(ext_modules=[Extension(name="mypackage.foo", sources=["src/.../foo.cpp"], ...), Extension(name="mypackage.bar", sources=["src/.../foo.cpp"], ...)], ...`