# python import path for sub modules if put in namespace package

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module, python-c-api

I have a python modules written in C, it has a main module and a submodule(name with a dot, not sure this can be called real submodule):

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC initsysipc(void) {
    PyObject *module = Py_InitModule3("sysipc", ...);
    ...
    init_sysipc_light();
}

static PyTypeObject FooType = { ... };
PyMODINIT_FUNC init_sysipc_light(void) {
    PyObject *module = Py_InitModule3("sysipc.light", ...);
    ...
    PyType_Ready(&FooType);
    PyModule_AddObject(module, "FooType", &FooType);
}
```

The module is compiled as `sysipc.so`, and when I put it in current directory, following import works without problem:

```
import sysipc
import sysipc.light
from sysipc.light import FooType
```

The problem is I want to put this module inside a namespace package, the folder structure is like this:

```
company/
company/__init__.py
company/dept/
company/dept/__init__.py
company/dept/sys/
company/dept/sys/__init__.py
company/dept/sys/sysipc.so
```

all the three `__init__.py` just includes the standard `setuptool` import line:

```
__path__ = __import__('pkgutil').extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

in current directory, following imports does not work:

```
from company.dept.sys import sysipc;
from company.dept.sys.sysipc.light import FooType;
```

How should I import the types and methods defined in module `sysipc.light` in this case?

===================================

Update with the actual error:

I have `sysipc.so` built, if I run python in current directory as this module, import will work as expected:

```
[root@08649fea17ef 2]# python2
Python 2.7.18 (default, Jul 20 2020, 00:00:00)
[GCC 10.1.1 20200507 (Red Hat 10.1.1-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sysipc
>>> import sysipc.light
>>>
```

If however if I put it into a namespace folder, like this:

```
company/
company/__init__.py
company/dept
company/dept/__init__.py
company/dept/sys
company/dept/sys/sysipc.so
company/dept/sys/__init__.py
```

import the submodule will not work:

```
>>> from company.dept.sys import sysipc
>>> from company.dept.sys import sysipc.light
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    from company.dept.sys import sysipc.light
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> from company.dept.sys.sysipc import light
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name light
>>>
```

The module is built with [this simple code](https://bpa.st/UQRQ), it is for python2. I also have [same example for python3](https://bpa.st/7TXA).

Comment: Thanks for the nice question, first of all. Looks insightful for me and my work. Here, my question would be would you mind telling how you're saying "following import works without a problem" like `import sysipc` because as far I know we will build and install the C file into the python module we desire (instead convert to .so) and which can be invoked in any files. Can you explain that part alone? need a little bit of info that how you tweak that?

Comment: Can you please provide the error message when trying to import the module? I tried to replicate the problem, but for me, the import works fine (except the auto-complete, since I did not include a stub)

Comment: i have updated the question with error messages and sample code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0489/#multiple-modules-in-one-library :

> To support multiple Python modules in one shared library, the library can export additional PyInit* symbols **besides the one that corresponds to the library's filename**.
>
> Note that this mechanism can currently only be used to **load** extra modules, **but not to find them**. (This is a limitation of the loader mechanism, which this PEP does not try to modify.) ...

In other words, you need to restructure the project as follows for `importlib` to be able to find the submodule `light` in the `sysipc` package:

```
company/__init__.py
company/dept/__init__.py
company/dept/sys/__init__.py
company/dept/sys/sysipc/__init__.py
company/dept/sys/sysipc/sysipc.so
company/dept/sys/sysipc/light.so -> sysipc.so  # hardlink
```

The hardlink between `light.so` and `sysipc.so` can be created with:

```
ln company/dept/sys/sysipc/sysipc.so company/dept/sys/sysipc/light.so
```

Then in `company/dept/sys/sysipc/__init__.py` you import all symbols from `sysipc.so` using:

```
from .sysipc import *
```

In addition, you need to change the name of the submodule C extension init function from  `init_sysipc_light` to `init_light` for Python2, or from `PyInit_sysipc_light` to `PyInit_light` for Python3, since `importlib` loads modules by looking for an exported `PyInit_<module name>` from the dynamic module and the module name here is only `light`, i.e., the parent package prefix is not part of the (sub)module name.

Here is the extension code (Python3) and a couple of functions for testing:

```
#include <Python.h>

PyObject *sysipc_light_foo(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
  printf("[*] sysipc.light.foo\n");
  return PyLong_FromLong(0);
}

static PyMethodDef sysipc_light_methods[] = {
    {"foo", (PyCFunction)sysipc_light_foo, METH_VARARGS, "sysipc.light.foo function"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef sysipc_light_module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "sysipc.light",
    "sysipc child module",
    -1,
    sysipc_light_methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_light(void)
{
    PyObject *module = NULL;

    module = PyModule_Create(&sysipc_light_module);

    return module;
}

PyObject *sysipc_bar(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
  printf("[*] sysipc.bar\n");
  return PyLong_FromLong(0);
}

static PyMethodDef sysipc_methods[] = {
    {"bar", (PyCFunction)sysipc_bar, METH_VARARGS, "sysipc.bar function"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef sysipc_module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "sysipc",
    "sysipc parent module",
    -1,
    sysipc_methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_sysipc(void)
{
    PyObject *module = NULL;

    module = PyModule_Create(&sysipc_module);

    PyInit_light();

    return module;
}
```

test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from company.dept.sys import sysipc
from company.dept.sys.sysipc import light

sysipc.bar() 
light.foo()
```

Output:

```
[*] sysipc.bar
[*] sysipc.light.foo
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52729181/5769463 the \_\_init\_\_.py can be used to plug-in a loader which would load the shared object and import right init-function, instead of creating links

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues here: first, `Py_InitModule` and friends expect to create the module being *imported*.  The hint is that the string you pass it is not the fully-qualified name of the module: Python uses the name it already knows to determine where in `sys.modules` to put the new object.  You can, however, use the **fully qualified** name; other magic attributes like `__file__` will have the correct values.

The second issue is that the **attribute** `light` needs to be set on the containing module for `from` imports to work.

Meanwhile, there's no reason to have a separate initialization function (that the interpreter will never call), and combining them avoids the need to recover a pointer to the module later:

```c
static PyTypeObject FooType = { ... };
PyMODINIT_FUNC initsysipc(void) {
    PyObject *module = Py_InitModule3("sysipc", ...);
    ...
    PyObject *const sub = Py_InitModule3("company.dept.sys.sysipc.light", ...);
    ...
    PyType_Ready(&FooType);
    // PyModule_AddObject steals a reference:
    Py_INCREF(FooType);
    PyModule_AddObject(sub, "FooType", &FooType);
    Py_INCREF(sub);
    PyModule_AddObject(module, "light", sub);
}
```

That said, `sysipc` will still not be a proper package: at the least, it lacks `__path__`.  If that matters, you might prefer [MEE's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64124420/8586227) that uses a real (if more complicated) package architecture.

Comment: My only discontent with this approach is that it forces the extension to be aware of, and hardcode, the expected location of the module in the package hierarchy.

Comment: @MEE: You could always examine the `__name__` of the top-level module if you wanted to make it portable that way.

Comment: can I do just `PyObject *const sub = Py_InitModule3("sysipc.light", ...);` instead of full module name?

Comment: @fluter: That’s basically MEE’s point—that it’s unfortunate that you have to fully qualify it.  My point was that you could compute it if desired.

Comment: i mean what if i just put "sysipc.light" ?

Comment: @fluter: Then `from company.dept.sys.sysipc.light import FooType` won’t work, because it won’t be in the correct place in `sys.modules`.

Comment: Because i'd like this module to be used in two ways, load from a namespace, like `comp.dept.sys.sysipc.light`, and without a namespace, that is to be able to load in current directory, just as `import sysipc.light`.

Comment: @fluter: That’s usually a design mistake (how would clients know under which name to import it?), but you can certainly use the `__name__` trick to do that.

Comment: what is the __name__ trick? can you give more details?

Comment: @fluter: I’ve already described it in this very comment thread: use `sysipc.__name__` (filled in by the import machinery, as hinted in the answer) to discover the enclosing package name (if any) and concatenate it with the suffix you want.

Comment: `sysipc.__name__` is python code, right? how should I do it in the C code?

Comment: @fluter: Consult the documentation, or ask a separate question, if you don’t know how to use the Python API to get attributes (and manipulate strings).