# Cython binary package compile issues

Tags: python-3.x, compilation, cython, setuptools, binaryfiles

I would like to compile a python3 package into a distributable binary form (without sourcecode) from within the *x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019* using python 3.6 (64bit). However, i have problems specifying the correct paths to the files the package should contain. The produced folder structure in the site-packages directory is all wrong and not what i expect from my source folder structure and my `setup.py`.
It seems for me that the modules from the top level package are treated differently, but i don't know exactly why this is the case.

My dir structure is the following:

```
.
├── hello
│   ├── hello1.py
│   ├── hello2.py
│   └── __init__.py
│   bye
│   ├── bye1.py
│   ├── bye2.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── setup.py
└── test
    └── test.py
```

The `__init__.py` from the `hello` package contains the line `from . import hello1, hello2, bye`, the `__init__.py` from the `bye` package contains the line `from . import bye1, bye2`.
The `hello1.py` and `hello2.py` contains a function `print_hello` and `print_hello2`, respectively, the `bye1.py` and `bye2.py` the functions `print_bye` as well as `print_bye2`.

To accomplish the compilation i set-up the following `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import Extension, setup, find_packages
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(name='hello',
      version='0.3',
      url='https://someurl',
      license='somelicense',
      author='Pepper Wutz',
      author_email='wutz@gmail.com',
      description='Prints "Hello World"',
      ext_modules=cythonize([Extension("hello", ["hello/*.py"]), Extension("hello.bye", ["hello/bye/*.py"]), language_level=3),
      zip_safe=False)
```

When i run this module from the top_level folder:

```
py -3.6 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

and then install it (from within the tests subfolder):

```
py -3.6 -m pip install dist/hello-0.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

i obtain the following output files:

```
Verzeichnis von C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages

18.01.2021  17:32    <DIR>          hello
18.01.2021  17:32    <DIR>          hello-0.3.dist-info
18.01.2021  17:32            20.480 hello.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
               1 Datei(en),         20.480 Bytes
               2 Verzeichnis(se), 15.070.900.224 Bytes frei

Verzeichnis von C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\hello

18.01.2021  17:32    <DIR>          .
18.01.2021  17:32    <DIR>          ..
18.01.2021  17:32            20.480 bye.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
               1 Datei(en),         20.480 Bytes
               2 Verzeichnis(se), 15.070.142.464 Bytes frei
```

Obviously, the folder structure of the hello package in the site-packages strongly differs from my original folder structure. E.g, the `hello.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` is put into the top-level scope and the bye package is put into the hello subdirectory respectively subscope. The `hello1` and `hello2` modules are not put into the hello package, but only the bye package. This completely messes up the relative imports which work when running the code from the interpreter:

```
C:\Users\User\source\repos\cython_tests\test>py -3.6 -c "import hello; print(dir(hello))"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "hello\__init__.py", line 1, in init hello
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Suspiciously, the `hello` folder containing the hello sources has only the `__init__.c` file but not `hello1.c` and `hello2.c`. The same goes for the `hello\bye` folder.

```
18.01.2021  17:27    <DIR>          .
18.01.2021  17:27    <DIR>          ..
18.01.2021  17:27    <DIR>          bye
18.01.2021  10:58               147 hello1.py
15.01.2021  20:11               150 hello2.py
18.01.2021  17:27           103.044 __init__.c
18.01.2021  17:20                35 __init__.py
               4 Datei(en),        103.376 Bytes
               3 Verzeichnis(se), 15.068.041.216 Bytes frei
```

I'm simply lost in writing the appropriate `setup.py`, especially specifying the `ext_modules`. I don't see what i did wrong. Maybe some other sees it.
What i want to obtain is a binary package which i can import using `import hello` and from which i can call the functions in hello1 and hello2 like this: `hello.hello1.print_hello()`, `hello.hello2.print_hello2()` as well as `hello.bye.bye1.print_bye()`, `hello.bye.bye2.print_bye2()`.

Comment: I had suggested [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157363/collapse-multiple-submodules-to-one-cython-extension) as a duplicate, but on close look I don't think it's quite what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the hop on and hop off with this question and the irritation this caused. I, today, invested several hours into this compilation issue and went two step forward, one backward and so on. @DavidW: I don't mind to compile each py module to a single .so(or .pyd) as far as the package hierarchy is maintained and the procedure doesn't spam the root dir of the site-packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want to do is create a package containing an extension module for *for each .py file*.

setup.py would contain:

```
      ext_modules=cythonize([
           Extension("hello.hello1", ["hello/hello1.py"]),
           Extension("hello.hello2", ["hello/hello2.py"]),
           Extension("bye.bye1", ["bye/bye1.py"]),
           Extension("bye.bye2", ["bye/bye2.py"]), language_level=3),
```

I've skipped the `__init__.py` files because there's usually little value in compiling them with Cython, and you have to work around a setuptools bug on Windows.

The upshot is that Python imports extension modules by searching for the module name first, then seeing if it has a `PyInit_<module_name>` function to call. When Cython compiles a file (e.g. `hello1.py`) it'll therefore create a `PyInit_hello1` function.

Therefore your supposed combined "hello" module ends up containing `PyInit_hello1`, `PyInit_hello2`, but no `PyInit_hello` and so doesn't import.

If you *really* want to bundle multiple modules together into a single .so file then you can follow the instructions in [Collapse multiple submodules to one Cython extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157363/collapse-multiple-submodules-to-one-cython-extension). You'll note that it isn't a built-in feature and it involves a lot of fine details of the Python import mechanism. Alternatively you could use some third-party tools designed to automated this (e.g. https://github.com/smok-serwis/snakehouse). I don't recommend this because it's complicated and likely a bit fragile.

Comment: First, thank you for the answer! I see that my wildcard usage was probably the reason for the misbehavior in that it included the unintended __init__.py files automatically. However, how can i workaround wildcard usage when i have more than a few files? Do i need to scan dirs and files using the os module to build up the Extension objects?

Comment: If I were doing it I'd probably scan dirs and files with the os module. I don't know if any more specific wildcard syntax is supported. Maybe `[a-zA-Z]*.py` but I suspect it won't work?

Comment: According to the docs linux style glob patterns are supported. Don't think this would help, either. Think, i'm going to implement that dir scanner, tomorrow.