# How can I compile Python projects into .pyd files?

Tags: python, compilation, pyqt, pyqt5, cython

I develop Windows desktop application with pyside2, in order to protect the source code, I need to compile these tens of *.py* files into *.pyd* files. At the beginning, I compiled the project with `Nuitka`. However, it doesn't support the Qt well enough unless with the *paid version*. Latter, I started to compile the Python files with Cython, and it worked.

However, a new issue pops up. When the application launches the first time after the Windows system launches, the application will take a long time to show up, even though the process has been started immediately. I guess it's due to the so many DLL files the application depends on that consume the time, because the latter launch of the application is much easier. The system must cache something for launched programs.

So, what if I make the *.pyd* files less, in which way, the system will spend less time to load necessary dependency for the application. But I don't know how to compile the several or more *.py* files into only one *.pyd* file. How?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157363/collapse-multiple-submodules-to-one-cython-extension

Comment: Be aware that all the solutions given in the linked answer are kind of hacky. This isn't really something that Cython is designed to support so you're largely on your own here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Cython only by passing all the py files as a parameter and hit run. The code sample is below:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(ext_modules=cythonize(["file1.py", "file2.py", "file3.py"]),)
```

Run this command in terminal
python setup.py build_ext --inplace

Comment: I need the compiled results as less as possible, instead of one .py file responding to one .pyd file